# Node Express AWS Subdomain and hosting another node app on subdomain

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I want to host another node app on sub domain.
How to create sub domain in aws and how to host another node app on sub domain?

Comment: Use the magic of AWS documentation it works everytime.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to create a subdomain in AWS. As soon as you configure your DNS records correctly for all subdomains to point to the right IP address of your server instance. Now, on your instance you may use a reverse proxy like nginx to dispatch the requests to a correct Node application because this will be easier than implementing that logic in your Node applications and will let you avoid tightly coupling of the Node applications and their current subdomains.

For details on the proxy configuration follow the links in this answer:

- [Django and Node processes for the same domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253823/django-and-node-processes-for-the-same-domain/43254532#43254532)